# How to scope TypeScript generic type with nested interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to create a generic interface for a function that accepts three argument. When filling in the first argument, the options of the second one  should be in the scope of the first. The third argument should then be in scope of the second argument.

My current code looks like this:

```
type SettingActionCreator<T> = <
  L extends T,
  K extends keyof L,
  C extends keyof L[K]
>(
  type: K,
  settingKey: keyof L[K],
  settingValue: L[K][C]
)

export interface SomeSettings {
  [Type.TypeA]: {
    settingA: "value1" | "value2";
    settingB: "value3 | "value4";
  };
  [Type.TypeB]: {
    ...
  };
  [Type.TypeC]: {
    ...
  };
}

const setSomeSetting: SettingActionCreator<SomeSettings> = (
  type,
  settingKey,
  settingValue
) =>
  // do something
```

So when I want to call `setSomeSetting` with arguments I expect that my scope becomes smaller for each argument I pass into it.

If for example I fill in the first argument, than the SettingActionCreator makes sure that the second argument (`settingKey`) can only be `settingA` or `settingB`. So far everything works as expected.

```
setSomeSetting(Type.TypeA, ....) // <-- settingKey accepts "settingA" and "settingB"
```

But for the third argument I can't seem to solve it. When I set the first argument and the second argument I would expect that the third argument would only accept the union options within the chosen `settingKey` argument. But instead of that I get all options within `Type.TypeA`. So both the settingValues of `settingA` and `settingB`

With this code:

```
setSomeSetting(Type.TypeA, "settingA", "value3") // <-- settingValue should only accept "value1" or "value2"
```

I would expect an error like:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '"value3"' is not assignable to parameter of type `"value1" | "value2"
```

But instead I get no type errors because it accepts both the values of `settingA` and `settingB`.

Does someone have a suggestion for what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you create a typescript playground link with a working example of the problem? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ It's a lot easier to answer a question like this with a working demo.

Comment: I'm not sure that what you want is entirely possible. The reason it's accepting both values of `settingA` and `settingB` is because they are all the values that fit the type system you've described. There's no way to narrow it down any further than that because that would require runtime information that doesn't exist when typescript is parsing.

I suggest you rework your design so the typing system is less nested, or maybe consider just throwing a runtime error for the final option

Comment: Idk, I suspect there's got to be a way to make this sort of thing work. If not with normal arguments, then it's got to work with a curried function, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to prove to TypeScript that the `settingKey` is related to the `settingValue` - the `settingKey: keyof L[K]` in your declaration is confusing it  (I'm not sure why - it *feels* like a bug that `type C extends keyof L[K] != keyof L[K]`, but it's definitely a limitation of the type inference code either way).

Change the type of that argument to `settingKey: C` and TypeScript will be able to understand the relationship between the three arguments:

```
type SettingActionCreator<T> = <
  L extends T,
  K extends keyof L,
  C extends keyof L[K]
>(
  type: K,
  settingKey: C, // <-- changed from keyof L[K]
  settingValue: L[K][C]
) => void;


declare const Type: {
  readonly TypeA: unique symbol,
  readonly TypeB: unique symbol,
  readonly TypeC: unique symbol
}

export interface SomeSettings {
  [Type.TypeA]: {
    settingA1: "valueA1" | "valueA2";
    settingA2: "valueA3" | "valueA4";
  },
  [Type.TypeB]: {
    settingB1: "valueB1" | "valueB2",
    settingB2: "valueB3" | "valueB4"
  },
  [Type.TypeC]: {
    //
  }
}

const setSomeSetting: SettingActionCreator<SomeSettings> = (
  type,
  settingKey,
  settingValue
) => {}
```

This results in the kind of error you are looking for:

```
setSomeSetting(Type.TypeB, "settingB1", "valueA3")
// Argument of type '"valueA3"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"valueB1" | "valueB2"'.
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works as expected. I'm still confused how `C` is different from `keyof L[K]`.